# How to insert in a sqlite database information that its in a button?

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

I am creating a database that saves questions. Each question has to be saved withs its Subject, Type, Level, Speed, Question, Answer. I know that with a textfield (question and answer) is done like this:

```
            pst.setString(5,contentQTextField.getText());
            pst.setString(6,answerQTextField.getText());
```

However, I have to access some information from buttons and I don't know how to do it.[How the buttons look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWG4t.png)

For example, I have to save in the database of what subject the question corresponds to and for this, the user has to click one of the radioButtons shown in the previous pic. So the program should know which button is clicked and save that information in the database. Moreover, I don't know how to do it with normal buttons (also shown in the picture) and with a slider [shown in the this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHK8W.png)

This is how my code looks like:

```
    addQButton = new Button("ADD QUESTION");

    //Adding more that one action to a button;
    addQButton.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, (e)-> {
        try
        {
            String query = "insert into Questions (Subject,Type,Level,Speed,Question,Answer) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = connectionQuestions.prepareStatement(query);
            //First question mark = 1, second = 2, etc.
            //pst.setString(1,);
            //pst.setString(2,);
            //pst.setString(3,);
            //pst.setString(4,speedSlider);
            pst.setString(5,contentQTextField.getText());
            pst.setString(6,answerQTextField.getText());


            pst.execute();

            System.out.println("Data saved");

            pst.close();

        }
        catch(Exception a)
        {
            System.out.println(a);
        }

        primaryStage.setScene(sceneAddQ);

    });
    addQButton.setPrefWidth(350.0);
    addQButton.setPrefHeight(50.0);
    addQButton.setStyle("-fx-font: 25 timesnewroman; -fx-base: #2EFE64; -fx-text-fill: black;");

    addQButtonPane.add(addQButton,3,21);
```

As you can see, I put in comments (//) the first 3 pst.setString because I don't know how to do it.

Thank you so much for you help in advance, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
int selectedRadio = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedRadio);
String text =  radioButton.getText();
```

You can get text from the radio button in this way, then simply just pass the value in  pst.setString(columnNo,text);

Comment: I am using a toggle group (javafx) to make the buttons mutually exclusive, I am not managing to save the selected radioButton and getting its text... Maybe it works different for toggle groups??

Comment: Nevermind, It works now!! Thank you so much for your help =)

Comment: did it help? or you found some other way?